# websphere startNode as a Linux Service

Tags: websphere, init

I have the following configuration
2 profiles

1st : ClusterManager it autostart at boot correctly because when I created it I was asked if I want to boot as a service

2nd : Node1 it doesn't autostart because I wasn't asked during the profile creation wizard (advanced mode)

I tried the following command:

```
./wasservice.sh -add was8-rd-dev1NodeCustom01 -serverName Node1 -profilePath /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Custom01/ -wasHome /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
```

but when I run the script in etc/init.d I got the following error:

com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ejs.EJSException: Could not register with Location Service Daemon, which could only reside in the NodeAgent. Make sure the NodeAgent for this node is up and running.

This is because the init script try to start startServer.sh instead of startNode.sh
I tried to change inside the init script but it throw an argument invalid error on the command line.

any clue on how to make it autostart ?

Comment: What is the exact error message?  Is it "ADMU9991E: Unknown option: serverName"?  If yes, you need to remove the argument to startServer.sh.

Comment: ADMU9991E: Unknown option: Node1
You mean remove 

    SERVERNAME="Node1"
?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the init script, but startNode.sh doesn't take a server name argument.  It looks like you left it on when you changed from startServer to startNode.

Comment: solved. I found some manual of websphere that say to not provide the nodeName to wasservice but the node server name. I don't know what's the difference between startNode Node1 and startServer nodeagent but seams none since it startsup all the appserver of the node as well.